# Cloud firestore setDoc() is not sending any data

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am having trouble sending data to Cloud Firestore with React Native. When a user triggers an update button, the app performs a Redux Async Thunk action to set the data to firestore using `setDoc()` but it did not resolve and sends data to the firestore.

I've debugged this issue and here is what I found so far. After a user clicks a button, it calls the `updateUserDetails()`. And that function will dispatch the async thunk action. Somewhere when this action happened, I received an error [Maximum range call stack error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYeO6.png)

The async thunk action will call `doc()` to create a Document instance. I have debugged the `doc()` function and there is no issue with it. And then, I call the `setDoc()` which did not resolve. I am not sure why it is not resolving?

**firebase/config.ts**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * as firebaseAuthentication from 'firebase/auth';
import * as firebaseStorage from 'firebase/storage';
import * as firestore from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth/react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  // Config in here. Sorry I cannot show but I promise it is correct
};

// Initialize Firebase
let app: firebase.FirebaseApp;
let auth: firebaseAuthentication.Auth;

if (firebase.getApps().length < 1) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  auth = firebaseAuthentication.initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
  });
} else {
  app = firebase.getApp();
  auth = firebaseAuthentication.getAuth();
}

export const firebaseApp = app;
export const firebaseAuth = auth;
export const firebaseDatabase = firestore.getFirestore();
export const firebaseAuthPackage = firebaseAuthentication;
export const firebaseAppPackage = firebase;
export const firebaseStorePackage = firestore;
export const firebaseStoragePackage = firebaseStorage;
```

**updateUserDetails() event handler function**

```
const updateUserDetails = () => {
    const details = {
      location: 'California',
      about_me: 'I love it! ',
      contacts: ['www.test.com', 'test@gmail.com'],
      socials: [
        { type: 'Facebook', value: '' },
        { type: 'Twitter', value: '' },
        { type: 'Instagram', value: '@vespid.my' },
      ],
    };
    dispatch(accountActions.updateAboutDetails(details));
  };
```

**updateUserDetails() async thunk function**

```
updateAboutDetails: async (
    packet: { location: string; about_me: string; contacts: string[]; socials: ISocials[] },
    thunkAPI: any,
  ) => {
    const { account } = thunkAPI.getState();
    const uid: string = account.account.uid.toString();
    const db = getFirestore();
    const document = doc(db, 'users', uid);
    // Add a new document in collection "cities"
    const updateAboutDetailsPromise = setDoc(document, packet)
      .then(() => {
        return packet;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
      });

    return updateAboutDetailsPromise;
  },
```

Comment: `updateUserDetails` not follow `redux-thunk` best practices - https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware

Comment: Feel free to reach at me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com for further assistance

Comment: I am using `createAsyncThunk()` from redux-toolkit to implement this.

Comment: Could do you reach me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com for further assistance

Comment: Having a similar issue with setDoc hanging (no errors too)

Comment: UPDATE: My issue was due AppCheck and Next 13 not working together.

Comment: I am also having this issue when using a firebase client in a heavily demanded local network. After some time, setDoc stop resolving.